# Repoint tortoiseSVN repository

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have a networked repository that i used to checkout files to my local working directory. That works fine. What i would like to do now is to take either the repository or local version and push that to a new repository. How can i do that? I'm basically trying to get my repository copied out of my network and into an online svn (project locker).
It's confusing to explain. I just want to temporarily point my local files to this online svn so i can push code out to there. Any suggestions

Comment: Doesn't the online provider have instructions as to how to import a repository with them?

Answer (score 6):

while you might be able to dump and load the repo into your hosted site, they may not give you access to a shell to load the dump into the new repository. You may be able to copy the repo directory but do *not* do this if you're changing platforms - eg going from a Windows to Linux host.

However, all this is not a problem - the easiest way is to use [svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnsync.html). Create a new repository (if it isn't already), then run:

```
svnsync init http://url/to/new/repo http://url/to/old/repo
```

You'll then need to set a pre-revprop-change hook to allow all changes (just 'exit 0' from the hook script)

Once that's done, just type:

```
svnsync --non-interactive sync http://url/to/new/repo
```

and it will replay each version from your current repository to the new one, so you end up with a perfect copy. You can interrupt the sync as you like, run it again and it will carry on from where it left off. (caveat: if you kill it with ctrl+c, you may need to remove the lock it uses. Type this to clear it)

```
svn propdel svn:sync-lock --revprop -r 0 http://url/to/new/repo
```

One big benefit is that you can use your existing repository as a backup afterwards, re-initialise the new repo to be the source and sync to your existing one, it'll replay all the latest commits as needed.

Comment: I think it's likely that a hosting facility will offer imports, as they can get new customers this way. Still, I like your approach better.

Comment: You never know with these host. Besides, I just like svnsync too much not to use it, it is brilliant.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a dump of your local repository, using `svnadmin dump`, and then upload the dump to the hosting facility in way so that you (or they) do `svnadmin load`. I don't think you can use Tortoise to produce the dump; you need the full svn installation.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the [SVN switch --relocate](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/re27.html) command.

Comment: relocate is used if repository has moved. he/she wants to move the contents of the repository

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to push changes into a different location, then you may be trying to "relocate" the repository to a new URL.  That is done by right clicking on the folder, choosing TortoiseSVN->Relocate.

Alternatively, if you're trying to create a NEW repository, you can just copy the folder, delete all of the .svn folders, and check in the entire directory to the new repository.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for the *svnadmin dump* solution unless you do not care about your history (then you just make check an export of your working copy). relocate etc does not do what you want (unless I understand you wrong)